# How to optimize the code to save data at GAE datastore?

Tags: python

I have the following code (for `Country` and `City` classes `key_name` is numeric id with addition of 'i' at the beginning):

```
def add_country(country, country_name):
  if country and country_namef and country_name != '':
    return Country.get_or_insert('i'+str(country), country_name=country_name)
  else:
    return None  

def add_city(city, city_name, country):
  if country and city and city_name and city_name != '':
    return City.get_or_insert('i'+str(city), city_name=city_name, parent=country)
  else:
    return None
```

Is it correct code or can it be optimized somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def add_country(country, country_name):
  if country and country_namef and country_name != '':
```

I assume that country_namef is a typo. If so, there is no point in checking `country_name != ''` because empty strings are already considered False

```
    return Country.get_or_insert('i'+str(country), country_name=country_name)
  else:
    return None  

def add_city(city, city_name, country):
  if country and city and city_name and city_name != '':
```

As before, empty strings are false, so you are checking that twice

```
    return City.get_or_insert('i'+str(city), city_name=city_name, parent=country)
  else:
    return None
```

Comment: So, in case when `country_name` is equal to `None` and when `country_name` is equal to `''`, in both cases `if country_name` returns `False`, right?

Comment: @LA_, yes that is correct.